# Wordpress - Include username and password into email template

Tags: wordpress, email, templates

I have a very simple code to send Wordpress users an email if their account has been approved.

I would also like to send the username and password into this email.

How would I do this ?

Here is the code I use to send the email.

```
<?php

add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));

/*--------------------------------
message received after account approval and account denied
------------------------------------*/
/**
* Modify the message sent to a user after being approved.
*
* @param $message The default message.
* @param $user The user who will receive the message.
* @return string the updated message.
*/
function my_custom_message( $message, $user ) {
$message = 'account approved, your login details are below:';
return $message;
}
function my_deniedcustom_message( $message, $user ) {
$message = 'Unfortunately you account has been denied membership';
return $message;
}
// add a new custom approval message
add_filter( 'new_user_approve_approve_user_message', 'my_custom_message' );

// add a new custom denial message
add_filter( 'new_user_approve_deny_user_message', 'my_deniedcustom_message' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can use the built-in `wp_new_user_notification()` function:

```
// Redefine user notification function
if ( !function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {

    function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $plaintext_pass = '' ) {

        $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

        $user_login = stripslashes( $user->user_login );
        $user_email = stripslashes( $user->user_email );

        $message  = sprintf( __('New user registration on %s:'), get_option('blogname') ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __('Username: %s'), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __('E-mail: %s'), $user_email ) . "\r\n";

        @wp_mail(
            get_option('admin_email'),
            sprintf(__('[%s] New User Registration'), get_option('blogname') ),
            $message
        );

        if ( empty( $plaintext_pass ) )
            return;

        $message  = __('Hi there,') . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __("Welcome to %s! Here's how to log in:"), get_option('blogname')) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __('Username: %s'), $user_login ) . "\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __('Password: %s'), $plaintext_pass ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= sprintf( __('If you have any problems, please contact me at %s.'), get_option('admin_email') ) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= __('Bye!');

        wp_mail(
            $user_email,
            sprintf( __('[%s] Your username and password'), get_option('blogname') ),
            $message
        );
    }
}
```

**Note:** If password is not passed to function, the newly registered user will not receive their welcome email.

Comment: Hi, that is what i was looking for, but Im not that good at PHP to make the above function work with my custom code. Any tips would be great, thanks

Comment: Just place this code in your theme's `function.php` file. If this file does not exists, then create it.

Comment: Perhaps I should have mentioned, Im using a plugin "new user approval" to moderate all new users, my above code send the email only when user approved.

Comment: OK, then place this code snippet in your plugin's main .php file.

Comment: Hi,thanksagain                                                      I tried your code, however the "new user approve" plugin overrides the email with its own.      Is it possible to include the user/pass in my custom code which works in place of the "new user approve" email

Comment: Maybe it is better to disable the plugin and use only the custom code. Or replace the `add_action()` function of the plugin to use this custom code, this however is not recommended, because when you update the plugin, the changes will gone.